# resetting form via jQuery not clearing ckeditor cktext_area field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ckeditor

I have following form

```
<div id="post-close-updates-form">
   <%= form_for [@investment,@post_close_update], remote: true  do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.cktext_area :content %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

and my jquery code is

```
$("#post-close-updates-form form")[0].reset();
```

but it is not clearing cktext_area content...while if i put normal html textarea then it works fine.

so how do i clear ckeditor cktext_area via js/jquery

Comment: Remove the second line of create.js.erb, does it clears the data from cktext_area field?

Comment: @Surya sorry for late response, i tried that but no success..also i added normal text_area which got cleared but not ckeditor cktext_area

Comment: hmm.. seems like DOM isn't being loaded for cktext_area in your form, otherwise it should have cleared the data from fields within the form.

Comment: actually i tried to clear it from browser console(ctrl + shift + j)  , and then $("#post-close-updates-form form")[0].reset();  but still no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok here is the answer given by developer of ckeditor @galetahub

```
$("#post-close-updates-form form")[0].reset();
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
  CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

but above one not worked for me so made some chages that works

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
   CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData(" ");
}
```

setData() is to set the data is cktext_area

now if u want to get the data from cktext_area in js then use this

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
   CKEDITOR.instances[instance].getData();
}
```